# Is this layout possible within the bootstrap column system?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5, but bootstrap 4 example would probably suffice.

Clearly, I can achieve this layout by not using bootstrap, but that's not what I'm trying to figure out. I'm wondering if I'm missing something in the bootstrap system, that I'm not making use of.

First, here's a screenshot of what I'm looking for.

[image]

Specs of layout:

- Container width: 1440px
- Grid gutter width: 32px
- 14 column layout

Each attempt presents it's own problem:

**1st attempt**(see code below) and problem: Orphans(in last row) get center aligned. They do not get left aligned.

**2nd attempt**(see code below): The parent (which is now the 12 col layout) is too small, so the columns aren't wide enough. The design calls for 370px width columns.

**3rd attempt**(see code below): Does not work for wrapping columns(obviously).

**1st attempt code:**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**2nd attempt code:**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-14 col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
                    <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**3rd attempt code:**

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-14 d-none d-xl-block col-xl-1"></div>
            <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></div>
            <div class="col-14 d-none d-xl-block col-xl-1"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Just to reiterate, only looking for bootstrap solutions. I can achieve this without bootstrap, but I wanted to see if I was missing something.

Comment: I don't believe the grid supports a class name of "col-14", however you can just use "col" and have a number of columns. You could put those in a div and set max widths and other modifiers as specified in the grid settings. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ . I once used the grid to make hundreds of icons on page using just repeated "col" classes. https://codepen.io/josdea/pen/owEbag

Comment: @Dean If you configure bootstrap with 14 columns, then `col-14` just is 100% width of the container width.

Comment: 14 7 4 and  12 6 3 will render the same as 3 2 1 . spacer column looks like horizontal padding . looking for a 14 column layout might be the wrong question/answer . Sorry not to help more than this, i do not get, understand your need of a 14 column base. My english is sometimes much too average ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using responsive breakpoints, yet looking for specific pixel widths. However, you should be able to use a nested layout and me-auto (margin-right: auto) to force the orphaned columns to the left.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1 border"><!--spacer--></div>
        <div class="col-md">
            <div class="row justify-content-center border">
                <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="border">col</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="border">col</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4">
                    <div class="border">col</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-14 col-md-7 col-lg-4 me-lg-auto me-0">
                    <div class="border">col</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 border"><!--spacer--></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://codeply.com/p/f2yCtBhfmf

EDIT: auto margin will push the column too far to the left since 14 doesn't divide evenly by 3. Therefore the layout isn't possible with 14 columns.

Comment: I hear you...At specific breakpoints I expect columns(and their inner content) to be match exact widths on a comp. So, you're correct that it's a responsive layout and those width will change.

Comment: Although this didn't solve my problem, it convinced that I'll need to alter the `col-lg-4`(in this case) class to achieve the layout I'm looking for. So, my case is probably more edge case.

Answer (score 0):

According to Bootstrap, Columns are centered on the page with the parent .container. then .row then a class with your chosen column size ex: .col-6 or .col col-lg-2
so maybe try

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is from their example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/